# Couldn't understand the difference between Object#taint and Object#trust in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

How does the below Object#methods differs from each other?

- *taint and trust*
- *untaint and untrust*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** As @themarketka pointed out, as of Ruby 2.2.2, trust has been deprecated and made equivalent to tainting.

---

The difference is rather odd, and not particularly well documented.

NOTE: At $SAFE level 0, none of these markers do anything at all.

## Tainting

The concept of tainting is whether an object comes from a trusted source. A string inputed from standard input is tainted, but a string that's just assigned is not. At higher safe levels, various potentially dangerous operations on tainted data are prohibited (throw `SecurityException`). Operations like `eval`, `system`, etc. Additionally, tainting can be inherited from so-called "child" objects:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > s = "Hi!"
 => "Hi!"
2.0.0p0 :002 > s.taint
 => "Hi!"
2.0.0p0 :003 > (s + "World").tainted?
 => true
```

So, if I do something like `system("rm -rf #{gets.chomp}")` (**DO NOT EXECUTE**) at a higher safe level, Ruby will complain as the combination of my untainted string (`"rm -rf #{...}"`) and a tainted string (`gets.chomp`) creates a tainted string.

## Trust

Trust is, unlike tainting, applicable to code, and objects. All running code is either trusted, or untrusted, and all objects are either trusted or untrusted. Untrusted code can only modify untrusted objects. Untrusted code can only create untrusted objects. Code and objects created at safe levels 0-2 are trusted, but anything running or created at $SAFE level 3 or 4 is untrusted, and can only modify untrusted objects.

## The Difference

The difference between tainting and trusting is subtle. Tainting is all about what *operations* you can conduct on data, but trust is about what data you can *access*. They protect different parts of the system. Additionally, while tainting always exists, and tainted objects can exist at any safe level, trust only comes into play at the so-called "sandboxing" $SAFE levels 3 and 4 which are almost exclusively used for sandboxing external code.

Comment: And two years later, [Ruby docs for 2.2.2](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-untrusted-3F) state that the `trust` methods are _deprecated_ and equivalent to their `taint` counterparts.